# I'm trying to calculate the total distance for a route with a multi waypoint in it, but total distance no showing

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>


<script type="text/javascript">


         var markers = [];

    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $.getJSON('json.json', function(data) {

    $.each(data.markers, function(i, marker) {
            markers.push(marker); 
     });  

    console.log(markers);                 
    });  

});

      window.onload = function () {


           var mapOptions = {
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
               zoom: 16,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN 
           };



           // var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    panel: document.getElementById('directionsPanel')
  //  suppressMarkers: true
  });


           var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
           var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

           var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);


 directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {

    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
  });

           var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#424242' });
           var lat_lng = new Array();
           for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
               var data = markers[i]
               var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
               lat_lng.push(myLatlng);


               function computeTotalDistance(result) {

          var total = 0;
          var myroute = result.markers[0];
          for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
            total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;


          }
          total = total / 1000;
          document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
        }

               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: myLatlng,
                   map: map,
                   title: data.title
               });
               (function (marker, data) {
                   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                       infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                       infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                   });
               })(marker, data);
           }
           for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
               if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {

                   var src = lat_lng[i];
                   var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                   path.push(src);
                   poly.setPath(path);

                   service.route({
                       origin: src,
                       destination: des,
                       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING


                   }, function (response, status) {
                       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            directionsDisplay.setDirections( response );
                       }
                       else {
      alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
    }
                           for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                               path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                           }

                   });
               }
           }
       } 



   </script

</html>
```

Comment: how to calculate total distance????

Comment: for example: (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable)

Comment: but these not free...

Comment: like a draggable directions

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question (especially on how to write a title). Also, you should edit your question instead of commenting if you want to add precisions.